# Meaning of 形 here?

Tags: meaning

I'm wondering what 形 and 形程度 mean in the following conversation. I know that 形 can be used quite figuratively but I never got a good feel for it.

A: しかしリーダーといっても形程度のことだろう？

B: 形で判断されることもあるでしょ？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「[形]{かたち}」, here, means "**token**" or "**by name only**".

A: "It's nothing more than a token leader, is it?"

B: "(But) you get judged by your name at times, y'know."

Comment: Thank you! Does this correspond with a specific dictionary definition of the word?

Comment: I doubt it as I used no dictionary in answering this question.  We (J-speakers) often use 形 to mean "token ~~" as opposed to "real ~~".

Comment: You find the definition in this way at Point 2 (イ) of 形・かたち like noted here:
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%BD%A2-463191